# How to highlight a file name in explorer panel using vscode api?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing an extension for VS Code. How can I highlight particular file in the explorer panel like git-lens does ? Basically I am making a code synchronization utility and I need to alert user about the files on local machine that are modified in relation to the remote code base.